# Height spacer (HeightSpacer) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) from https://developer.android.com. [image for code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4VXh.png)
But I can't import HeightSpacer.
Is HeightSpacer deprecated? I can't find any new alternatives for that? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LayoutHeight` is deprecated. Use this instead:

`Spacer(modifier = Modifier.preferredHeight(16.dp))`

Comment: the documentation of spacer says `Component that represents an empty space layout, whose size can be defined using Modifier.width, Modifier.height and Modifier.size modifiers.`

Answer (score 25):

You can use a `Spacer` with a `height` modifier—or any other modifier(s) that you like.  For example:

```kotlin
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
```